# Google Analytics for iOS not dispatching events

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the latest SDK version, and the basic code to register and send a page view:

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-MY_ACCOUNT_ID-1"
                                           dispatchPeriod:10
                                                 delegate:self];

NSError *error;

if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"/firstpage"
                                     withError:&error]) {
  NSLog(@"tracker failed: %@",error);
}
```

However the events are not dispatched from the device or simulator. There are no errors as well. When i turn on the debug flag, i can see the following:

```
dispatch called
dispatching 4 events
[after 10 seconds]
dispatch called
...dispatcher was busy
[after 10 seconds]
dispatch called
...dispatcher was busy
```

My delegate method never gets called:

```
- (void)trackerDispatchDidComplete:(GANTracker *)tracker
                  eventsDispatched:(NSUInteger)eventsDispatched
              eventsFailedDispatch:(NSUInteger)eventsFailedDispatch{
    NSLog(@"success: %d failures: %d",eventsDispatched,eventsFailedDispatch);
}
```

- I tried to create a new publisher ID but it did not help as well.
- I do have internet connection from the device and simulator
- I deleted the app before trying.
- I played with the dispatch period - setting it to -1 and call the dispatch manually

Nothing helped.... :(

I'm struggling with this for a day now... how can i make it work?

Comment: eventually i got it to work so here is the solution in case someone else encounter it: the problem was that i had a call to  [[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch] somewhere in code (while settings the dispatch period to -1). And that part of code was running in a background thread. You must call all GANTracker on the same thread.. and it works.

Comment: It does state this in the SDK docs under Known Issues, but I missed this also ... https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/devguide ... Thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the dispatcher ("...dispatcher was busy"). In my case, it was because I had run my app normally in the background, and it was using the dispatcher. When I tried to connect the device to Xcode to run and debug the app, the console showed me that message. So the solution was easy:

- Stop the app in Xcode
- Close the app in background

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

you can put after calling the GANTracker a manual dispatch like that:
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch];
and it work perfectly