# "dispatcher was busy" of google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am doing some statics on my app by google analytics.
I downloaded the easyTracker demo yesterday and it works very well. 
But today it does not work well any more. 
Below shows the log in Xcode:

```
2012-04-24 16:52:03.757 EasyTrackerExample[1514:f803] dispatch called
2012-04-24 16:52:03.759 EasyTrackerExample[1514:f803] ...dispatcher was busy
2012-04-24 16:52:13.758 EasyTrackerExample[1514:f803] dispatch called
2012-04-24 16:52:13.759 EasyTrackerExample[1514:f803] ...dispatcher was busy
```

What I have done was I replaced the accountId with my personal id "UA-xxxxxxxx-1", and no other changes.
I doubt that whether there is something wrong with Google analytics server

Anyone who can give me a hand will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202030/google-analytics-for-ios-not-dispatching-events

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. It was due to the fact that following my last update of my development environment (Eclipse and ADT), I had to add the jar file of the Google Analytics SDK to the "libs" folder (before this update, everything worked well with the jar file just mentioned in the Build Paths but after the update the Google Analytics tracker could not instantiate anymore). After adding the jar file to the libs folder, the Google Analytics tracker could instantiate but I had your error message. I simply removed the jar file from my Build Paths (just left it in the libs folder)...and it works !!