# Google Analytics on iOS returning NO on dispatch, no debug output

Tags: ios, google-analytics

In trying to implement the Google Analytics SDK for iOS, I've run into two brick walls.

The first one is that after executing this code in `application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-XXXXXXX-YY"
                                       dispatchPeriod:10
                                             delegate:self];
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] setDebug:YES];
```

.. and then trying to track anything or call `dispatch`, no debug messages are logged whatsoever. I've added `NSLog` lines before and after tracking calls and the code is definitely being reached.

Secondly, when I do try and do a manual dispatch, it returns `NO`. All the other issues I've seen online are where `dispatch` returns `YES` but it's somehow not going through properly. What does one do if `dispatch` actually returns `NO`?

I've tried adding an `NSError *` reference to the track methods and those actually succeed (no error, function returns `YES`). But the events are definitely not being periodically dispatched, since we're seeing nothing on the GA account more than 24 hours later.

*EDIT:* I've also got `NSLog` calls in both of the delegate methods (`hitDispatched:` and `trackerDispatchDidComplete:eventsDispatched:eventsFailedDispatch:`), and neither of those are being called either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*cough*

I'd misspelled the `#define` to start the tracker object in my app delegate. Other files were spelled correctly, hence the logging statements showing up, but when I tried to log just before the tracker was started it didn't show.

Oops. Well, at least there's a decent troubleshooting post for Google Analytics on SO now!

Answer (score 1):

i think you should check this to delegate method of GANTracker

```
- (void)trackerDispatchDidComplete:(GANTracker *)tracker
              eventsDispatched:(NSUInteger)hitsDispatched
          eventsFailedDispatch:(NSUInteger)hitsFailedDispatch{

//print or check number of events failed or success

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've already got methods implemented for those, and I've set the delegate correctly, but I don't see any logging statements from either method. The methods are not being called by the `GANTracker` instance. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Delegate is set to 'nil' instead of class instance which implements the delegate methods.    
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-XXXXXXX-YY"
                                   dispatchPeriod:10
                                         delegate:nil];
```

In your case, assuming that UIApplicationDelegate may be implementing **GANTrackerDelegate**, the message call should set delegate as **' self '**.

Cheers!! 
Amar.

Comment: Hmm, dunno how that `nil` got in there. I'll double-check my code but I think it's definitely already set to `self`..

Comment: Browsing through SO I have found 2 more cases where dispatch didn't work. Check if any of these are applicable in your case.  1. Try deleting the application from simulator/device and reinstalling it - [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682380/problem-dispatching-with-google-mobile-analytics-for-iphone)  2. When dispatch is getting called from thread other than one from which **startTrackerWithAccountID:dispatchPeriod:delegate:** is called - [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202030/google-analytics-for-ios-not-dispatching-events)

Comment: Your answer was the closest to the actual problem, so I'm awarding you the bounty amount.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the dispatch is relying on the calling thread's run loop - Is it possible you are running this from a secondary thread, one which might not exist by the time the dispatch is suppose to call you back?

Answer (score 0):

You've not enabled dryRun have you? Double check with:

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] setDryRun:NO];
```

Also try dispatchSynchronous, it'll block as it's sending but might help with if things aren't on the same threads:

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatchSynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just've checked it from scratch, dispatch perfectly worked meaning

a) your device is somehow different (i still have unsolved crashes on the particular iPad's 3 from Apple tester's unresolved, so it wouldn't be a huge surprise)

b) your code is somehow different - and that's much easier for you to fix.

---

For the a) there's no advice but to test it against all the devices you might get, for the b) i could only say what worked for me:

- downloaded 1.4 SDK [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources)
- got Google sample projects with   `git clone https://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev.analytics-end-to-end/`
- configured final/AnalyticsSample to launch, changed the source slightly

(trackEvent::::: were called from sample, app was restarted manually as there's zero time period requiring dispatch call)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:kGANAccountId
                                         dispatchPeriod:0
                                               delegate:self];

    NSLog(@"Dispatch%@", [[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch] ? @"ed Successfully": @" Failed");

  [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```

That's it, log says `Dispatched Successfully`, worth trying i guess.